# How can I generate deb installable file for my ROS package(python code in the script folder)?

Tags: python, debian, package, ros, deb

How can I generate deb installable file from the python files in my package(in the script folder), so I can deliver the deb file to the client who can run the python executables in the package?

For example, I just completed the ROS tutorial and created the beginner_tutorials package in my catkin workspace. I also completed the Simple Publisher and Subscriber tutorials which mean the python talker.py and listener.py in the script folder in the beginner_tutorials package.Then I run the following command in the package folder,~/ROS/catkin_workspace/src/beginner_tutorials:

$ bloom-generate rosdebian --os-name ubuntu --ros-distro kinetic

$ fakeroot debian/rules binary

So it generated the deb file. After I installed the deb to a new machine and I try to run the command:

$ rosrun beginner_tutorials talker

$ rosrun beginner_tutorials talker.py

$ rosrun beginner_tutorials listener

$ rosrun beginner_tutorials listener.py

After the installation on the new machine. I can't run the talker and listener. There is no python file in the /opt/ros/kinetic/lib. but look inside of the deb file, there are python files in the /opt/ros/kinetic/lib folder. I don't know where the python file went after install the deb file. I was wondering how can I export the package with python script to a installable deb file and after I install the deb file on a new machine, I can run the python executable file on the new machine?

If someone can give me some hints or guidance, I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Jue Wang(Patrick)

Answer (score 1):

You may just use CPack with following options:

(Package-wide `CMakeLists.txt` file)

```
#############
## Install ##
#############

set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")

#Creating UNIX structured package
set(CPACK_CMAKE_GENERATOR "Unix Makefiles")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../..")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION 0.2.9)

#Set directory to /../ to avoid /share part of ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX "$ENV{ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}/../")
set(CPACK_INSTALL_CMAKE_PROJECTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR};${PROJECT_NAME};ALL;/./")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY
    "${PROJECT_NAME} - ${PROJECT_DESCRIPTION}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "RCS")

#Now we can simply create the dependencies using almost the same package names as they declared in ROS repository
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "ros-kinetic-roscpp, ros-kinetic-std-msgs, ros-kinetic-message-runtime, ros-kinetic-sensor-msgs")

#IMPORTANT: set this to keep on auto-introspection for system dependencies like libc++6
set (CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS ON)

#Keep Debian package structure untouched
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_STRICT_PERMISSION TRUE)

#Standard naming schema for Debian-based distros
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}~${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}_${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "Technical University")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT "<your@email.com>")

#Turn the process on    
include(CPack)
```

In case of simple catkin package structure you can simply uncomment and edit `install` sections of your `CMakeLists.txt` according to files your package required to install. Then run

```
catkin_make package
```

After that you will have the `.deb` package archive in the root directory of your ROS package. Now you can use `dpkg-deb -c` command to ensure the paths defined within the package are correct. To obtain the example download and examine any ROS package from the official binaries repository.